# How to use Doxygen tableofcontents command

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to use tableofcontents command from [Doxygen Doc](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdtableofcontents).

To me `\tableofcontents['{'[option[:level]][,option[:level]]*'}']` seems very cryptic.
Could you give an example of how to pass options and levels?

Comment: What did you try so far? Which doxygen version.

Answer (score 3):

From the doxygen documentation:

> 24.111 \tableofcontents['{'[option[:level]][,option[:level]]'}']
>
> Creates a table of contents at the top of a page, listing all sections and subsections in the page. The option can
> be HTML or LaTeX or XML or DocBook. When a level is specified this means the maximum nesting level that
> is shown. The value of level should be in the range 1..5, values outside this range are considered to be 5. In
> case no level is specified level is set to 5 (show all) In case no option. is specified \tableofcontents
> acts as if just the option HTML and XML was specified. In case of multiple \tableofcontents commands
> in a page the option(s)

See also the beginning of the chapter "Special Commands" where a small description is of some of the used symbols.

So e.g.:

```
\tableofcontents
\tableofcontents{HTML}
\tableofcontents{HTML:3}
\tableofcontents{HTML:2,LaTex:3}
```